# Hypocorism/diminutive name forms in Roman antiquity/Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, names, roman-culture

I'd originally asked this on SE:H, but it was suggested that here would be more appropriate.

Triggered by recently reading about the history of English names with Anglo-Saxon roots and the development of diminutive forms, I'd started wondering:

What do we know about hypocorism/diminutive name forms in Latin names in Roman antiquity? Or to use a modern analogue, if friends and family call *William* and *Harold*, *Will* (or even Willie?) and *Harry*, then did friends and family of Romans like *Julius Caesar*, in private, use forms like (pure speculation here) ... *cull* for *Caius* -> *Caiulus* -> *cullus* -> *cull*.

Note, I'm not talking about "nicknames" here, known in Roman times as *cognomen*, so not names like *cicero*, *niger*, *ahenobarbus*, etc.

As per Wikipedia

> A hypocorism, from Ancient Greek ὑποκόρισμα (hypokorisma), from
>   ὑποκορίζεσθαι (hypokorizesthai), meaning 'to use child-talk' is a
>   diminutive form of a name. Hypocorisms include pet names or calling
>   names, often a, diminutive or augmentative form of a word or given
>   name when used as a nickname or term of endearment

I tried doing some research, first into given names in Latin, of which lists are plentiful. We're all familiar with *Marcus*, *Lucius*, *Caius*, *Claudia*, and so on.

Then reading up on diminutive word forms in Latin. Many will know about the -ulus/-ula forms, but this interesting link lists others used in the language: [The Formation of Latin 
Diminutives of Nouns and Adjectives](http://diesgaudii.genvid.com/latin/diminutives/diminutives.pdf)

On English names the article [Behind the Name – Diminutive](https://www.behindthename.com/glossary/view/diminutive) explains

> A diminutive (or pet name) of a given name is a short and/or
>   affectionate form. Often they are only used by friends and relatives.
>
> Short forms
>
> The most common diminutives (at least among English names) are those
>   that are short forms of the original name, very often from the first
>   syllable or sound of the name. For example, Alex is from Alexander,
>   Barb is from Barbara, Deb is from Deborah, and Mike is from Michael.
>   Other short forms don't come from the beginning of the name, but
>   instead from the end or the middle, like Beth from Elizabeth, Fred
>   from Alfred, Greta from Margareta, and Lisa from Elisabeth.

But nowhere could I find anything that would show pet names used in ancient Rome. Did Romans really always use the full given name, and maybe with the Latin diminutive form? The link above states that -ill- and -tt-

> [are] found  used  only  with  feminine names,  but  it  could
>   theoretically  also  be  used  with others words, e.g. a masculine
>   form of Līvilla would be Līvillus.

So, Caesar's mum called him *Caius* and maybe *Caiulus*, but no known pet name form of *Caius*? Was *Marcus Ulpius Traianus* never called *Marc* (or at least the appellative form *Marce*?) Seeing as how Romans abbreviated inscriptions, could we end up with *M.Ulp.Trai*. as *Mulpe* among very close friends or at least before Trajan was raised to office and emperorship?

The detailed Wiki article [on Roman naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_naming_conventions) makes note that

> Roman men were usually known by their praenomina to members of their
>   family and household, clientes and close friends; but outside of this
>   circle, they might be called by their nomen, cognomen, or any
>   combination of praenomen, nomen, and cognomen that was sufficient to
>   distinguish them from other men with similar names. In the literature
>   of the Republic, and on all formal occasions, such as when a senator
>   was called upon to speak, it was customary to address a citizen by
>   praenomen and nomen; or, if this were insufficient to distinguish him
>   from other members of the gens, by praenomen and cognomen.

and on the cognomen

> Unlike the nomen, which was passed down unchanged from father to son,
>   cognomina could appear and disappear almost at will. They were not
>   normally chosen by the persons who bore them, but were earned or
>   bestowed by others, **which may account for the wide variety of
>   unflattering names that were used as cognomina. Doubtless some
>   cognomina were used ironically, while others continued in use largely
>   because, whatever their origin, they were useful for distinguishing
>   among individuals and between branches of large families**. New
>   cognomina were coined and came into fashion throughout Roman
>   history.

But while the former indicates that there was *Marcus* but no *Marc*, the latter (with my emphasis) indicates that it's unlikely even his closest friends and family (such as they were) would have called *Nero*... well, *Nero* to his face!

Are there no Latin hypocoric name forms similar to *William* -> *Bill*, *Richard* -> *Dick*, *Ann* -> *Nancy*, *Helen* -> *Nellie*?

Comment: I can't find any evidence of shortened names in the corpus but I did stumble upon a longstanding academic debate about the name _ipsitilla_ in Catullus 32, a probable diminutive superlative of _ipsa_ and, therefore, a term of endearment (albeit facetious in tone).  Is this sort of what you're after?  Or do you only want shortened names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never heard of such hypocoric variants of Roman names.
It has hard to prove non-existence, so we will have to wait to see if others agree.
If no user here has heard of something, it has very slim — but admittedly non-zero — chances to exist.

One noteworthy thing about Roman *praenomina* is that there is not much room for abbreviation.
The Roman given names are relatively short, having often one syllable for the stem and another one for the ending.
Latin is an inflected language and dropping endings will not work quite the same way it does in English.
If *Caius* becomes *Cull* (a more likely spelling would have been *Cul*), how do you form the genitive, dative, or accusative?
It doesn't sound like any simplification to me to turn the second declension *Caius, Caii* to a third declension *Cul, Cullis*.

Also, I wouldn't draw too deep conclusions from abbreviations in inscriptions.
Space was far more expensive than today.
Of course it is possible that some would read them as *M. Ulp. Trai. > Mulpus*, but I imagine that would have come across as mockery rather than affection.

Comment: It's almost amazing to me that we have no record of this. With human nature being what it is, you'd think there'd be *some* form of pet names. Possibly in the vulgar, which we have so few records of? But I don't recall anything in Petronius either, who used a few snippets.

Comment: @Marakai Affectionate address need not have anything to do with the names. For example, you could call William "honey" instead of "Bill". Our written evidence is limited, but as far as I know, it contains no hints at affectionate variants of Roman names.

Comment: You misunderstand me when using "pet names". In this case I was simply too lazy to write *hypocorism* and just used *pet names* instead, not implying whether they were addresses of affection. Of course, now you made we write hypocorism. Twice!

Comment: @Marakai Unless I'm mistaken, all pet-names, regardless of shortening or not, are hypocorism. "Sweetie-pie" is hypocorism. See the "Did you know?" section on [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocorism).

Comment: After long last decided to accept this one as at least an explanation of why we do NOT see this.

Comment: @Marakai Questions like this are tricky in that respect. If the answer is that something doesn't exist, it's very hard to prove it conclusively.

Answer (score 0):

The only example I can think of is with *Catellus* and *Lesbia* (*Clodia*?) but I wouldn't be surprised if hypocorism wasn't wide spread though for a few reasons:

- Ancient Roman culture was considerably different with very different morals and if you consider the population of Rome divided up between slaves (basically objects rather than people so did their names even matter?), non-citizens (probably foreign and have non-Roman names, or adopted *cognomina*), plebeians and the equestrian and patrician classes, it seems to me that a person's name was very important in identifying themselves in society (especially for equestrians and patricians if they entered into public life) so Roman citizens were probably very proud of them and it likely wasn't the sort of thing that most Romans subscribed to out of respect.
- The use of *cognomina* (and that nouns in Latin decline) also suggests to me that if Romans did use hypocorism, it would be more like in the Catallus' / Lesbia situation where a person's *cognomina* would be replaced with one more flattering rather than their *praenomina* being shortened.
- I think it would also more likely to have been the domain of artists and poets who didn't have more important things to do.

Comment: Can you explain your example?

Comment: The poet Gaius Valerius Catullus wrote a number of poems in which he refers to a women named "Lesbia" (thought to be Clodia Metelli his lover and a married woman). The name Lesbia roughly translates as 'Women from Lesbos' which is an affectionate name typical of hypocorism considering he could have picked any other name to use in his poems if he simply wanted to just distance himself from her...

Comment: So, a couple things. I believe the OP is specifically looking for shortening, for which this would not fit. Also, Lesbia is certainly not a "pet-name." One, he uses the name all throughout the Lesbia cycle, even when he's bad-mouthing or slandering her. There's no way we can conclude that it's anything more than an allusion to Sappho (who was a woman from Lesbos) working as a pseudonym for Clodia. Following your logic, we would have to conclude that Lesbius from [c. 79](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Catullus_79) is also a pet-name for Clodius Pulcher, which cannot be right.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it does seem a bit speculative and based on opinion. In your example my first though would have been "alias" to protect the identity of the woman in question. Not what you would associate with a pet name.